# Java Regex error/issue (what kind of character is [ )?

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I am trying to write an array to a text file, and in the process I have noticed that arrays are written in the format of: `[1, 1, 2, 2]` (an example of an int array) and I want to convert an array, take the int array above as an example, convert it to a string and remove the `[` and `,` from it. How can I go about doing it, I've tried looking for a string pattern I could write and had no luck, I have also tried writing:

```
char [] PIN = System.console().readPassword();
    String pin = java.util.Arrays.toString(PIN);
    String WriteToF = pin.replaceAll("[", "");
```

but get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed char
acter class near index 0
[
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
```

Also what kind of a character is `[` classed as in Java in terms of [These patterns?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: When the regex engine see a `[` character then it considered as a start of a character class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regex `[` is considered as a special meta character(start of a charcter class). To match a literal `[`,  you need to escape `[` symbol when passing it to `replaceAll` function.

```
String WriteToF = pin.replaceAll("\\[", "");
```

When the regex engine see a `[` character then it considered it as a start of a character class.  If a character class is opened then it must be closed using `]`(*`]` means the end of character class.*).

so that only you get the below error.

```
Unclosed character class near index 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method replaces using regex. If you want to replace the literal `[` character, you should use the [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method:

```
String WriteToF = pin.replace("[", "");
```

In regex, the `[` character marks the beginning of a character class. You need to close the character class with `]` for it to be valid regex syntax. If you wanted to replace the *literal* `[` character with regex, you would escape it: `"\\[`".

Answer (score 0):

1. use `replaceAll("\\[", "")` instead.
2. `[` is to represent the beginner of Character classes, which need to be escaped when matching `[` literally.